# WooCommerce: "account is already registered with your email address"

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, account, email-verification

We have a newsletter signup on our site. When someone signs up, wordpress creates a subscriber account associated with their email address (no password needed). If one of these users then goes to purchase products from us using the same email address, and they tick the box for "create an account" on the checkout page, they get this error:

**An account is already registered with your email address. Please log in.**

But they can't log in because their original subscriber account doesn't have a password associated with it, and there's no option to add a password to the existing account or reset the password or anything.

Any suggestions on how to handle this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like the Newsletter Sign-Up logic is flawed in the way you're setting it up - why are user accounts without passwords being created?